# Show a message in GUI while a thread is running in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0

I have an application that upon first start up and every 7 days performs an update downloading some files from the web.

This update can take up to 5 minutes depending on how many files require downloading.

What I'm thinking of doing is running the update in a separate thread so that the rest of the GUI is usable while the update is processing.

This seems like a pretty viable option for my application but I would also like to show a message in the main GUI, possibly in a status bar, that tells the user that the update is processing and goes away when it is finished.

I've searched around for ways to do this but nothing seems to pop out as the solution I'm looking for.  Does anyone know if this is possible and how to do it?

Comment: Use the [`BackgroundWorker` component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

Comment: Show us the code so we can build on it!! Otherwise you'll get super generic answers ;)

Answer (score 6):

All you need to do is wrap your UI-accessing code with a [`Dispatcher.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx) call from the background thread. The `Dispatcher` instance to use may be obtained through the [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject.dispatcher.aspx) property of your `UIElement`.

Assuming that the method below is defined within your UI element’s class definition:

```
private void ProcessItems(IList<Item> items)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; ++i)
        {
            // Code here runs on background thread.
            this.ProcessItem(items[i]);

            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                // Code here runs on UI thread.
                this.UpdateStatus("Completed " + (i + 1) + " of " + items.Count);
            });
        }
    },
        TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}
```

Comment: Yes, a GUI must be WPF nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

With this little guy:

```
internal static class ControlExtensions
{
    internal static void Invoke(this Control control, Action action)
    {
        control.Invoke(action);
    }
 }
```

you can call in you code (in win form world, wpf has own solution):

```
... form.Invoke(()=>form.SomeControl.SomeProperty=someValue);
```